# Get Opportunity StageName from helper class on OppLineItem

Tags: apex, soql, opportunity-lineitem

I'm trying to get the Opportunity Stage value from the Opp Line Item Object but my query returns a null value. What am I missing in my "If" statement?

```
public static void updateClasses(List<OpportunityLineItem> newList){
        Map<Id, Id> olIds = new Map<Id, Id>();


        for(OpportunityLineItem ol : newList){
        system.debug('----------olOpp Stage Name------------'+ol.Opportunity.StageName);
            if(ol.Opportunity.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
            olIds.put(ol.Id, ol.Class__c);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

You cannot get the related object's(opportunity in this case) field info without actually querying for it.

```
public static void updateClasses(List<OpportunityLineItem> newList){
            Map<Id, Id> olIds = new Map<Id, Id>();
    for(OpportunityLineItem ol : [select id,Class__c,opportunity.stagename from opportunitylineitem where Id IN: newList]){
            system.debug('----------olOpp Stage Name------------'+ol.Opportunity.StageName);
                if(ol.Opportunity.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
                olIds.put(ol.Id, ol.name);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rao, if I don't Limit that query, will I hit governor limits?

Comment: @user7505 duh sorry about the limit, I was testing that in my dev console. Cut paste error updated the answer